# C Timer with cancellation and call back

Tags: c, linux, timer, pthreads, cancellation

I've created a Timer pseudo class in C that has call back capability and can be cancelled.  I come from the .NET/C# world where this is all done by the framework and I'm not an expert with pthreads.

In .NET there are cancellation tokens which you can wait on which means I don't need to worry so much about the nuts and bolts.

However using pthreads is a bit more low level than I am used to so my question is:

Are there any issues with the way I have implemented this?

Thanks in anticipation for any comments you may have.

Timer struct:

```
typedef struct _timer
{
    pthread_cond_t Condition;
    pthread_mutex_t ConditionMutex;
    bool IsRunning;
    pthread_mutex_t StateMutex;
    pthread_t Thread;
    int TimeoutMicroseconds;
    void * Context;
    void (*Callback)(bool isCancelled, void * context);
} TimerObject, *Timer;
```

C Module:

```
static void *
TimerTask(Timer timer)
{
    struct timespec timespec;
    struct timeval now;
    int returnValue = 0;
  
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &timespec);
    timespec.tv_sec += timer->TimeoutMicroseconds / 1000000;
    timespec.tv_nsec += (timer->TimeoutMicroseconds % 1000000) * 1000000;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&timer->StateMutex);
    timer->IsRunning = true;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&timer->StateMutex);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&timer->ConditionMutex);
    returnValue = pthread_cond_timedwait(&timer->Condition, &timer->ConditionMutex, &timespec);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&timer->ConditionMutex);
   
    if (timer->Callback != NULL)
    {
        (*timer->Callback)(returnValue != ETIMEDOUT, timer->Context);
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&timer->StateMutex);
    timer->IsRunning = false;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&timer->StateMutex);

    return 0;
}

void
Timer_Initialize(Timer timer, void (*callback)(bool isCancelled, void * context))
{
    pthread_mutex_init(&timer->ConditionMutex, NULL);
    timer->IsRunning = false;
    timer->Callback = callback;
    pthread_mutex_init(&timer->StateMutex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&timer->Condition, NULL);
}

bool
Timer_IsRunning(Timer timer)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&timer->StateMutex);
    bool isRunning = timer->IsRunning;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&timer->StateMutex);

    return isRunning;
}

void
Timer_Start(Timer timer, int timeoutMicroseconds, void * context)
{
    timer->Context = context;
    timer->TimeoutMicroseconds = timeoutMicroseconds;

    pthread_create(&timer->Thread, NULL, TimerTask, (void *)timer);
}

void
Timer_Stop(Timer timer)
{
    void * returnValue;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&timer->StateMutex);
    if (!timer->IsRunning)
    {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&timer->StateMutex);
        return;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&timer->StateMutex);

    pthread_cond_broadcast(&timer->Condition);
    pthread_join(timer->Thread, &returnValue);
}

void
Timer_WaitFor(Timer timer)
{
    void * returnValue;

    pthread_join(timer->Thread, &returnValue);
}
```

Example use:

```
    void
    TimerExpiredCallback(bool cancelled, void * context)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "TimerExpiredCallback %s with context %s\n",
            cancelled ? "Cancelled" : "Timed Out",
            (char *)context);
    }
        
    void
    ThreadedTimerExpireTest()
    {
        TimerObject timerObject;
        
        Timer_Initialize(&timerObject, TimerExpiredCallback);
        Timer_Start(&timerObject, 5 * 1000000, "Threaded Timer Expire Test");
        Timer_WaitFor(&timerObject);
   }

    void
    ThreadedTimerCancelTest()
    {
        TimerObject timerObject;
        
        Timer_Initialize(&timerObject, TimerExpiredCallback);
        Timer_Start(&timerObject, 5 * 1000000, "Threaded Timer Cancel Test");
        Timer_Stop(&timerObject);
   }
```

Comment: Do not hide pointer nature behind a typedef (as your `Timer` does).  It is more confusing than helpful.

Comment: Read [time(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html). Consider also using some event loop (e.g [libevent](https://libevent.org/) or [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/), etc...). Read some [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) and [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) with [signal(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

Answer (score 2):

Overall, it seems pretty solid work for someone who ordinarily works in different languages and who has little pthreads experience.  The idea seems to revolve around `pthread_cond_timedwait()` to achieve a programmable delay with a convenient cancellation mechanism.  That's not unreasonable, but there are, indeed, a few problems.

For one, **your condition variable usage is non-idiomatic**.  The conventional and idiomatic use of a condition variable associates with each wait a condition for whether the thread is clear to proceed.  This is tested, under protection of the mutex, before waiting.  If the condition is satisfied then no wait is performed.  It is tested again after each wakeup, because there is a variety of scenarios in which a thread may return from waiting even though it is not actually clear to proceed.  In these cases, it loops back and waits again.

I see at least two such possibilities with your timer:

1. The timer is cancelled very quickly, before its thread starts to wait.  Condition variables do not queue signals, so in this case the cancellation would be ineffective.  This is a form of race condition.
2. Spurious wakeup.  This is always a possibility that must be considered.  Spurious wakeups are rare under most circumstances, but they really do happen.

It seems natural to me to address that by generalizing your `IsRunning` to cover more states, perhaps something more like

```
    enum { NEW, RUNNING, STOPPING, FINISHED, ERROR } State;
```

, instead.

Of course, you still have to test that under protection of the appropriate mutex, which brings me to my next point: **one mutex should suffice**.  That one can and should serve both to protect shared state and as the mutex associated with the CV wait.  This, too, is idiomatic.  It would lead to code in `TimerTask()` more like this:

```
    // ...

    pthread_mutex_lock(&timer->StateMutex);

    // Responsibility for setting the state to RUNNING transferred to Timer_Start()
    while (timer->State == RUNNING) {
        returnValue = pthread_cond_timedwait(&timer->Condition, &timer->StateMutex, &timespec);

        switch (returnValue) {
            case 0:
                if (timer->State == STOPPING) {
                    timer->State = FINISHED;
                }
                break;
            case ETIMEDOUT:
                timer->State = FINISHED;
                break;
            default:
                timer->State = ERROR;
                break;
        }
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&timer->StateMutex);

    // ...
```

The accompanying `Timer_Start()` and `Timer_Stop()` would be something like this:

```
void Timer_Start(Timer timer, int timeoutMicroseconds, void * context) {
    timer->Context = context;
    timer->TimeoutMicroseconds = timeoutMicroseconds;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&timer->StateMutex);
    timer->state = RUNNING;
    // start the thread before releasing the mutex so that no one can see state
    // RUNNING before the thread is actually running
    pthread_create(&timer->Thread, NULL, TimerTask, (void *)timer);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&timer->StateMutex);
}
```

```
void Timer_Stop(Timer timer) {
    _Bool should_join = 0;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&timer->StateMutex);
    switch (timer->State) {
        case NEW:
            timer->state = FINISHED;
            break;
        case RUNNING:
            timer->state = STOPPING;
            should_join = 1;
            break;
        case STOPPING:
            should_join = 1;
            break;
        // else no action
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&timer->StateMutex);

    // Harmless if the timer has already stopped:
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&timer->Condition);

    if (should_join) {
        pthread_join(timer->Thread, NULL);
    }
}
```

A few other, smaller adjustments would be needed elsewhere.

Additionally, although the example code above omits it for clarity, you really should ensure that you **test the return values of *all* the functions that provide status information** that way, unless you don't care whether they succeeded.  That includes almost all standard library and Pthreads functions.  What you should do in the event that that one fails is highly contextual, but pretending (or assuming) that it succeeded, instead, is rarely a good choice.

### An alternative

Another approach to a cancellable delay would revolve around [`select()` or `pselect()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) with a timeout.  To arrange for cancellation, you set up a [pipe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html), and have `select()` to listen to the read end.  Writing anything to the write end will then wake `select()`.

This is in several ways easier to code, because you don't need any mutexes or condition variables.  Also, data written to a pipe persists until it is read (or the pipe is closed), which smooths out some of the timing-related issues that the CV-based approach has to code around.

With `select`, however, you need to be prepared to deal with signals (at minimum by blocking them), and the timeout is a duration, not an absolute time.

Answer (score 1):

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&timer->StateMutex);
timer->IsRunning = true;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&timer->StateMutex);

pthread_mutex_lock(&timer->ConditionMutex);
returnValue = pthread_cond_timedwait(&timer->Condition, &timer->ConditionMutex, &timespec);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&timer->ConditionMutex);

if (timer->Callback != NULL)
{
    (*timer->Callback)(returnValue != ETIMEDOUT, timer->Context);
}
```

You have two bugs here.

1. A cancellation can slip in after `IsRunning` is set to `true` and before `pthread_cond_timedwait` gets called. In this case, you'll wait out the entire timer. This bug exists because `ConditionMutex` doesn't protect any shared state. To use a condition variable properly, the mutex associated with the condition variable *must* protect the shared state. You can't trade the right mutex for the wrong mutex and then call `pthread_cond_timedwait` because that creates a race condition. The entire point of a condition variable is to provide an atomic "unlock and wait" operation to prevent this race condition and your code goes to effort to break that logic.
2. You don't check the return value of `pthread_cond_timedwait`. If neither the timeout has expired nor cancellation has been requested, you call the callback anyway. Condition variables are stateless. It is your responsibility to track and check state, the condition variable will not do this for you. You need to call `pthread_cond_timedwait` in a loop until either the `state` is set to `STOPPING` or the timeout is reached. Note that the mutex associated with the condition variable, as in 1 above, *must* protect the shared state -- in this case `state`.

I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding about how condition variable work and what they're for. They are used when you a mutex that protects shared state and you want to wait *for that shared state* to change. The mutex associated with the condition variable must protect the shared state to avoid the classic race condition where the state changes after you released the lock but before you managed to start waiting.

UPDATE:

To provide some more useful information, let me briefly explain what a condition variable is for. Say you have some shared state protected by a mutex. And say some thread can't make forward progress until that shared state changes.

You have a problem. You have to hold the mutex that protects the shared state to see what the state is. When you see that it's in the wrong state, you need to wait. But you also need to release the mutex or no other thread can change the shared state.

But if you unlock the mutex and then wait (which is what your code does above!) you have a race condition. After you unlock the mutex but before you wait, another thread can acquire the mutex and change the shared state such that you no longer want to wait. So you need an atomic "unlock the mutex and wait" operation.

That is the purpose, and the only purpose, of condition variables. So you can atomically release the mutex that protects some shared state and wait for a sign with no change for the signal to be lost in-between when you released the mutex and when you waited.

Another important point -- condition variables are stateless. They have no idea what you are waiting for. You must never call `pthread_cond_wait` or `pthread_cond_timedwait` and make assumptions about the state. You *must* check it yourself. Your code releases the mutex after `pthread_cond_timedwait` returns. You only want to do that if the call times out.

If `pthread_cond_timedwait` doesn't timeout (or, in any case, when `pthread_cond_wait` returns), you don't know what happened until you check the state. That's why these functions re-acquire the mutex -- so you can check the state and decide what to do. This is why these functions are almost always called in a loop -- if the thing you're waiting for still hasn't happened (which you determine by checking the shared state that you are responsible for), you need to keep waiting.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for  your comments.  I'm sure I am misunderstanding some of the concepts being as this is the first time I have used them,  But the documentation and examples available on-line to me are not very useful.  The documentation almost assumes prior knowledge which is ridiculous and the examples are so complex as to be useless.  Once I have grasped the concepts I will write an idiots guide based on my experience.

Comment: @Tim I provided some additional information that I hope is helpful.